# "Quarterly round trip to populate the cloud"

Tags: backup, cloud

A friend has asked me to look over a proposal for an IT infrastructure in her startup.

In the "Backup" section of the proposal, cloud-based image backups are offered, but it states that as part of this, it features:

"Quarterly round trip to populate the cloud"

What exactly does this mean?!  Is it a full system image that is taken and uploaded 4x per year?  And all other backups are incremental/differentials, perhaps?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest asking whoever wrote the proposal. That doesn't make any sense in English.

Comment: The best course of action would be to ask the party that's making the proposal. We would have no idea of what they meant by that statement.

Comment: Agreed, thanks.  If someone adds an answer to that effect, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I suspect (hope) they mean they're going to ship physical media to an offsite backup facility but to be honest, I would be extremely wary of anyone who uses the term "cloud" in a technical proposal. It's a marketing term and even there I would suggest its losing whatever currency it once had.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best course of action would be to ask the party that's making the proposal. We would have no idea of what they meant by that statement - they aren't using industry insider terminology that would make sense to someone in the "know".

Comment: Maybe they're taking a station wagon full of tapes on a trip to the clouds?  Just need a catapult that could put a station wagon up that high.